# Firebase Real Time: How to query constraint database dynamically (eg limitToFirst, orderByChild...)?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am trying to dynamically apply query constraint to my queries, which I usually do with mongoDb.

Here is my code:

```js
async function getAll(path, query = {}) {

    const promise = firebaseDatabase.ref(path)

    for (const [queryType, queryConstr] of Object.entries(query)) {
        // Example:
        // queryType   == 'limitToFirst'
        // queryConstr == 1
        promise[queryType](queryConstr)
        // so this results in `promise.limitToFirst(1)`
    }

    const snapshot = await promise.get() // I also tried with .once('value')

    return snapshot.val() || {}
}
```

Unfortunately **this code is not working** and returns all the data.

On the other hand, the below code **works** but **is not dynamic**:

```js
async function getAll(path, query = {}) {

    const promise = firebaseDatabase.ref(path).limitToFirst(1) // chaining it directly works

    const snapshot = await promise.get() // I also tried with .once('value')

    return snapshot.val() || {}
}
```

- Could you explain why the first example is not working ?
- Would it be possible to add query constraint dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of trial and errors here is the version I have came up with, which works but is very **hacky** IMO.

So this may help while awaiting for a better solution and **I will remove my answer as soon as there is a cleaner way to do so**

```js
async function getAll(path, query = {}) {

    if (query && Object.keys(query).length) {
        let promise

        const queryAsArr = Object.entries(query).sort((a, b) => a[0] === 'orderByChild' ? -1 : 1)

        if (queryAsArr.length === 1) {
            const [[queryType, queryConstr]] = queryAsArr
            promise = firebaseDatabase.ref(path)[queryType](queryConstr)
        } else if (queryAsArr.length === 2) {
            const [[queryType1, queryConstr1], [queryType2, queryConstr2]] = queryAsArr
            promise = firebaseDatabase.ref(path)[queryType1](queryConstr1)[queryType2](queryConstr2)
        } else if (queryAsArr.length === 3) {
            const [[queryType1, queryConstr1], [queryType2, queryConstr2], [queryType3, queryConstr3]] = queryAsArr
            promise = firebaseDatabase.ref(path)[queryType1](queryConstr1)[queryType2](queryConstr2)[queryType3](queryConstr3)
        } else {
            error.serverError('Query object in getAll() do not accept more than 3 filters for the moment', { query })
        }

        const snapshot = await promise.get()

        const result = snapshot.val() || {}
        return await firebaseAfterRequest(ctx, baseConfig, 'getAll', result)
    } else {
        const snapshot = await firebaseDatabase.ref(path).get()
        const result = snapshot.val() || {}
        return await firebaseAfterRequest(ctx, baseConfig, 'getAll', result)
    }
}
```